# LINQ: Get records in list with the largest values for property

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know how simple it is,

I have an object like

```
public class ActionRecord
{
    public int RecID { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string ActArea { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActDate { get; set; }
}
```

The sample data in ActionRecord can be like following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
RecID      Action      ActArea      UserID      ActDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1       Edit        Main 1 Item      5        2014-11-01 10:01:14
   2       Delete      Sub 1 Item       2        2014-11-01 14:22:58
   3       Add         Sub 5 Item       2        2014-11-01 15:16:03
   4       Add         Sub 6 Item       2        2014-11-01 15:48:32
   5       Edit        Main 1 Item      2        2014-11-01 16:04:50
   7       Edit        Main 2 Item      5        2014-11-01 16:19:03
   8       Delete      Main 2 Item      5        2014-11-01 16:38:49
   9       Add         Main 3 Item      2        2014-11-01 16:42:25
  10       Edit        Main 3 Item      3        2014-11-01 16:45:38
```

My requirement is that with the help of LINQ I need to filter data so that I may only get the LATEST Action on the ActArea, here is what the final data should look like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
RecID      Action      ActArea      UserID      ActDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  10       Edit        Main 3 Item      3        2014-11-01 16:45:38
   8       Delete      Main 2 Item      5        2014-11-01 16:38:49
   5       Edit        Main 1 Item      2        2014-11-01 16:04:50
   4       Add         Sub 6 Item       2        2014-11-01 15:48:32
   3       Add         Sub 5 Item       2        2014-11-01 15:16:03
   2       Delete      Sub 1 Item       2        2014-11-01 14:22:58
```

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, couldn't get what to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with GroupBy:

```
var res = dara.GroupBy(d=>d.ActArea)
    .Select(g=>g.OrderBydescending(a=>a.ActDate).First());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
var latest =
    from x in all
    group x by x.ActArea into gxs
    from gx in gxs
        .OrderByDescending(y => y.ActDate)
        .Take(1)
    select gx;
```

The result I get is:

[image: Results]

This matches the requirement albiet that it's not in the same order.